# What is a magical array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reverse

In the Perl [documentation for `reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) I find this:

*"Note that reversing an array to itself (as in @a = reverse @a ) will preserve non-existent elements whenever possible; i.e., for **non-magical arrays** or for tied arrays with EXISTS and DELETE methods."*

What properties differentiate a magical from a non-magical array?

Comment: The `@_` array is "magical".

Comment: The `@_` array is not magical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *magical* array is one where an operation performed on it does more than simply alter the contents. The only built-in array that has magic is `@ISA`, and that is in a very non-obvious way. As the sentence implies, a magical array is mostly a *tied* array, See [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) and [`perltie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html)

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks. I didn't see what mob was getting at

Answer (score 12):

Magical variables are those that have special features that a normal variables of that type do not have.

See [Magic Variables in perlguts](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlguts#Magic-Variables). See also [Variable::Magic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Variable::Magic) which lets you "Associate user-defined magic to variables from Perl."

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, it's possible to have operations on a variable trigger the calling of code.

For example,

```
use Variable::Magic qw( wizard cast );

my $wiz = wizard(
   get  => sub { print "get\n" },
   set  => sub { print "set\n" },
);

cast my $x, $wiz;

$x = 1; print("$x\n");
$x = 2; print("$x\n");
```

outputs

```
set
get
1
set
get
2
```

Such variables are said to have magic.

Many of the variables in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) are magical. For example, `$!` uses magic to proxy `errno` and `strerror`.

```
$ perl -E'for (1..5) { $! = $_; say $!; }'
Operation not permitted
No such file or directory
No such process
Interrupted system call
Input/output error

$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump($!)'
SV = PVMG(0x292fdf0) at 0x28f9648
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (GMG,SMG)        <--- Has get and set magic
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0
  MAGIC = 0x28e0f50
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_sv
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_sv(\0)
    MG_OBJ = 0x28f9660
    MG_LEN = 1
    MG_PTR = 0x2903230 "!"
```

This is just one of the many uses of magic in core. Search for "The current kinds of Magic" in [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html) for a number of others, including lvalue `substr`.

```
# When substr is used as an lvalue, it returns a
# magical variable that changes $s when it's changed.
substr($s, 0, 1) = "abc";
```

[`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) uses magic to expose something similar to magic to Perl code.

Magical hashes and arrays are rarer than magical scalars. `%ENV` proxies `getenv` and `putenv`. `@ISA` has magic to invalidate method lookup caches.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump(@ISA, 0);'
SV = PVAV(0x1087e88) at 0x10a3a78
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (SMG,RMG)        <--- Has set and other magic
  MAGIC = 0x108b380
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_isa
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_isa(I)
    MG_OBJ = 0x10a3a90
  ARRAY = 0x0
  FILL = -1
  MAX = -1
  ARYLEN = 0x0
  FLAGS = (REAL)
```